# how to redefine a TStringList type variable

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, tstringlist

I have some problem. i can't redefine variable correctly by following code.

```
      UnitObj.prjOne:=ReturnRightList(0);
      for j:=0 to UnitObj.prjOne.Count-1 do
            str:=UnitObj.prjOne.ValueFromIndex[j];//here i get for example '32'

      UnitObj.prjTwo:=ReturnRightList(1);
      for j:=0 to UnitObj.prjTwo.Count-1 do
            str1:=UnitObj.prjTwo.ValueFromIndex[j];//here i get for example '40'

       for j:=0 to UnitObj.prjOne.Count-1 do
          str4:=UnitObj.prjOne.ValueFromIndex[j]; // WHY HERE I GET '42' instead of '32' 

      UnitObj.prjThird:=ReturnRightList(2);
      for j:=0 to UnitObj.prjThird.Count-1 do
            str2:=UnitObj.prjThird.ValueFromIndex[j];//here i get for example '42'


procedure TfrmLogin.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  roleList:=TStringList.Create;
end;
function TfrmLogin.ReturnRightList(bPos:integer):TStringList;
var sqlString:string;
begin
  roleList.Clear();
  case bPos of
       0:sqlString0;//some sql queries
       1:sqlString1;
       2:sqlString2;      
  end;
      SQLQueryPrjRight.Close;
      SQLQueryPrjRight.SQL.Strings[5]:=sqlString;
      SQLQueryPrjRight.ParamByName('ID').Value:=uInfo.ID;
      SQLQueryPrjRight.Open;
      while not SQLQueryPrjRight.EOF do
                begin
             roleList.Add(IntToStr(SQLQueryPrjRight.FieldByName('pID').AsInteger));
             SQLQueryPrjRight.Next;
            end;
  Result:=roleList;
end;
```

In function ReturnRightList i fill in a TStringList roleList that assigned to prjOne, prjTwo, prjThird. But after this i get three TStringLists whith the same contents. Why does it happen and how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: rolelList should be an array of 3 TStringLists. Modify the code to create roleList[0], roleList[1], roleList[2] and change the code to deal with the appropriate TStringList each time.

Answer (score 2):

You only have a single instance of the string list. Note that you only called `TStringList.Create` once. Hence only a single instance. Each time you populate a list you are populating the same list instance, overwriting the previous content.

You need to instantiate three distinct instances. I cannot really tell you how exactly to implement this because I cannot see all of your program. However you will need to call `TStringList.Create` three times, one for each list, storing those newly created lists in your variables `prjOne`, `prjTwo` and `prjThree`. You also need to remove `roleList` which serves no use.

The key to understanding all of this is the concept of a reference type. A class is a reference type. So a variable of type `TStringList` is a reference to an instance. That is a pointer to an instance. When you assign to a reference type variable you are copying the reference (pointer) and not copying the value. This means that in your code all three variables `prjXXX` refer to or point to the same object instance.

Comment: Ok, but i don't understand how i need to use three distinct intances in this case

Comment: You need three different lists but you only have one. How can one list hold three different values?